# ASP.Net MVC dropdown list data missing from model on POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

I am passing a dropdownlist as part of my view model to the Create view.

ViewModel:

```
public class VendorVM
{
    public Entities.Vendor Vendor { get; set; }

    public SelectList VendorParentList { get; set; }
    public string VendorParentSelected { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.VendorParentSelected, new SelectList(Model.VendorParentList, "Value", "Text"), "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddVendorParent" })
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    VendorVM theVendorVM = new VendorVM();
    theVendorVM.Vendor = new Entities.Vendor();

    List<Entities.Vendor> theVendorList = BLL.GetData.RetrieveVendorParents();
    theVendorVM.VendorParentList = new SelectList(theVendorList, "ID", "Name");

    return View(theVendorVM);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(VendorVM theVendorVM)
{
    try
    {
        Entities.Vendor theVendor = new Entities.Vendor();
        Entities.Vendor theVendorParent = new Entities.Vendor();

        if (theVendorVM.VendorParentSelected != null)
        { theVendorParent.ID = Convert.ToInt32(theVendorVM.VendorParentSelected); }
        theVendorVM.Vendor.VendorParent = theVendorParent;

        // Store the Vendor 
        theVendor = BLL.StoreData.InsertVendor(theVendorVM.Vendor);

        theVendor.Errors.Add("Holy Cannoli!!!");

        if (theVendor.HasErrors)
        {
            foreach (String err in theVendor.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, err);
            }
            return View(theVendorVM);
        }
        else { return RedirectToAction("Index"); }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I get the POST back from the View, VendorParentList == NULL.

I am faking a server-side error here with "Holy Cannoli".  I want to be able to maintain ViewModel state and re-display the View with errors.

Why is the ViewModel.VendorParentList null?  The Vendor object contains the correct values.  Any List in the Viewmodel I send to the View comes back to the POST as null.

How can I fix this.  Or, better, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's how posting works in a form. Only form controls are posted(inputs, ddls, hiddenfields, textarea, etc). Not the entire viewmodel. Why not get your viewmodel or lists from db again in post?

Comment: This is what I am doing now.  Seems awfully wasteful to have to request from DB again or build session variable for caching. 
You mention dd's, however they are not returned - which is the issue.  I must capture the selections made, but the entire dd is not posted.

Comment: By ddls, I meant the selected value in the drop-down list. Not the  entire dropdownlist. Coming from webforms you might find it weird but posting only the info that is needed minimises the data transfered to the server. If you really need to post the select list, use a for loop and hidden fields for vendorlist item inside the form.

Answer (score 1):

Oh i think i get the question. You want the dropdownlist to be populated in case of an error. When you post a form, the dropdownlist doesn't get posted with the ViewModel, just the selected ID. In case of an error, you will have to repopulate (re-create) the ViewBag (or in your case the View-model Property) that holds the menu for it to be loaded again. So just before the line `return View(theVendorVM);`, you should add

```
List<Entities.Vendor> theVendorList = BLL.GetData.RetrieveVendorParents();
theVendorVM.VendorParentList = new SelectList(theVendorList, "ID", "Name");
```

That way, the property is loaded with the menu before the View is returned with the model.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am doing.  I just thought it silly to have to go back to the DB or a cached version for this when all I really want to do it re-display the page to allow the errors to be corrected.   I suspect that I was just spoiled with ViewState in the webform world.  

I was hoping that this was a shortcoming of mine and not the MVC Framework.  Apparently, I am the only one to complain about this.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is null is because on the page there is an html form and that form will only post back the form values on it.  I.e. the values for VendorParentList are not included because they are not on the form.

You are not necessarily doing anything wrong.  As mentioned in the comments a lot of the time sending back this information would be a waste of resources.  This is a nice situation because you have the opportunity to taylor the behaviour to
to the needs of your application.

If for your application you think its a problem and you want to send back the values to avoid a database connection on post back then as imAbhi said you can use hidden fields.  Here's how it could work.

Change your viewmodel to

```
public class VendorVM
{
    public Entities.Vendor Vendor { get; set; }

    public IList<Parent> VendorParentList { get; set; }  //Ilist instead of SelectList 
    public string VendorParentSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Change your view to this, note how I have passed "Id" and "Name" into the select list here rather than in the controller.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.VendorParentSelected, new SelectList(Model.VendorParentList, "Id", "Name"), "-- Select --", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", id = "ddVendorParent" })

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.VendorParentList.Count; i++)
    {
        <input type="hidden" name="VendorParentList[@i].Id" value="@Model.VendorParentList[i].Id" />
        <input type="hidden" name="VendorParentList[@i].Name" value="@Model.VendorParentList[i].Name" />
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
}
```

I have assumed your Parent class looks like this

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //other fields
}
```

Now on postback you will find that your VendorParentList will be populated with values.

Comment: Thank you Dave.  I see how you are handling this.
My issue is with what is "assumed" to be in the Posted back form and what it not there.
VendorParentList is part of the Model  and the Form - is NOT sent back with the POST

VendorParentSelected is part of the Model and the Form - IS sent back with the POST

In my mind, the entire form with ALL of the object should be posted and it is up to the Controller to use or ignore it.  

I realize that I am fighting City Hall and this is apparently a logic exercise. 
Upvoted